# Qt QMimeDatabase header is not included

Tags: c++, qt, debian

I am trying to port a Qt application from Windows to Linux. The build system complains `QMimeDatabase.h` is unknown even though it is clearly in the include directory.

I am using the latest Debian version and Gnome. Qt version is 5.10 with g++ 6.30.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `QMimeDatabase`, without `.h` suffix. If you look into this file, you'd see it actually includes `qmimedatabase.h` - note the lower case. On Windows the file system is case insensitive while on Linux it is case sensitive, so on Windows `QMimeDatabase.h` and `qmimedatabase.h` is the same file while on Linux they are recognized as different files - `qmimedatabase.h` is present but `QMimeDatabase.h` is not.

Comment: This was the issue. Header was spelled `QMimeDataBase` instead of QMimeDatabase`.